# Error in my jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

Hello i have this error and i don't know I do not know what that means

> Attribute value "listLienDoc_"+i+"" is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the value

Thx..

Comment: Advice: to check right quotation use an editor, like notepad++ or jedit. They supports syntax higlighting and that is often useful for preventation such annoying erros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<html:select styleId="<%="listLienDoc_"+i+""%>"
```

with

```
<html:select styleId='<%="listLienDoc_"+i %>'
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is this statement: `"<%="listLienDoc_"+i+""%>"`

at least the `+""` is useless - you can remove it.

And then put the complete argument value in `'` instead of `"` - may you should do this with all the other arguments to, because it is always better to not nest `"`.

```
<html:select
   styleId='<%="listLienDoc_"+i%>'
   name="typeLien" property="listUtilitaireBean.typeLien"
   value="<%=typeLien.toString()%>"
   onchange="<%="changeList("+i+");"%>"
   indexed="true">
```

On the other hand my you do it complete different:

`<html:select styleId="listLienDoc_<%=i%>" ...`